# Almost complex manifold of dimension 2... locally isomorphic to ℂ?

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces

I know that this is supposed to be standard, but I don't know how to search for it... hence the question:

> Let $J$ be an almost complex structure on $M:=\mathbb R^2$, i.e., a $C^\infty$ section of $\mathrm{End}(TM)$ which squares to $-\mathrm{id}_{TM}$.
>
> How does one prove that $(M,J)$ is *integrable*, i.e. how does one prove that it is locally isomorphic to $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Hi this absolutely isn’t my field but... I think one can show the vanishing of the Nijenhuis tensor easily: N_J(X, X) = 0 and N_J(X, JX) = 0 by inspection. Let me know if I’ve said something dumb (true with high probability)!

Comment: If you can find a vector field $X$ on a neighborhood U such that $[X,JX]=0$ on $U$, then that neighborhood is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. This is because the Lie bracket is the obstruction to $X,JX$ "integrating" to a coordinate grid

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17565/newlander-nirenberg-for-surfaces/22019#22019

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eckmann-Frölicher say so right after they introduce the (“Nijenhuis”) torsion tensor in ([1951](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=42202), [p. 2284](http://gallica2.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k31848.f2288)), bottom: “dans $\mathrm E_2$, $t^j_{kl}$ est toujours $=0$.”

And this was known to imply integrability in the plane, as Newlander-Nirenberg start by recalling with proof in ([1957](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=88770), p. 394):[image]

On p. 392 they also write

> For $n=1$ the compatibility conditions are vacuous and the problem becomes that of introducing isothermal coordinates with respect to the Riemannian metric $ds^2=|dz + ad\bar z|^2$

— a problem whose solution Lichtenstein ([1919](//zbmath.org/?q=an:47.0450.01), §24e, [p. 264](//archive.org/details/encyklomath3102encyrich/page/264)) traces back to Gauss ([1825](//archive.org/details/werkecarlf04gausrich/page/n198)); I would add Lagrange’s *Sur la construction des Cartes Géographiques* (1781, [pp. 167-169](http://bibliothek.bbaw.de/bbaw/bibliothek-digital/digitalequellen/schriften/anzeige/index_html?band=03-nouv/1779&seite:int=230)).